# run console jobs from yii2-basic

Tags: php, cron, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to run a cron job in yii2-basic for that we are create controller in commands folder  that is :-

```
<?php
 namespace app\commands;
 use yii\console\Controller;
 class IndexController extends Controller
 {
   public function actionIndex()
   {
     echo "message ";
   }
}
```

and when run this commands in terminal php yii index/index its working correctly but when I add this code in index function  :-

```
    $checkblogsql=TblBlog::find()->all();
    $totalblogcount=count($checkblogsql);
```

its showing error :-

```
    Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

    invar/www/html/ameborcam/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:550
```

my db connectivity is correct becaouse Main site is working correctly.
Thank you

Comment: did you add the details in console config file?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yes this is my console file
$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');
$config = [    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            ],
        ],

Comment: looks like your cron jobs are not able to link the app with drivers of database

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo please tell me where I am wrong

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I am running the action like this :-    php yii index/index

Comment: you are using yii2 , basic theme right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yes I am using basic yii2

Answer (score 0):

Your CLI (console) PHP is probably different from CGI (web) PHP. You can check current CLI PHP version by running in console

```
php -v
```

If this is the case you must configure your CLI PHP with proper database modules so database driver can be used.

For currently installed CLI modules run

```
php -m
```

Comment: @Bizely PHP 7.1.2-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2017 11:40:07) ( NTS )

Comment: and is there something among its modules that suggests your database is supported?